# R Test if Specific Groups of Values are in ID Group

Tags: r, regex, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset where I'm trying to label members that have all categories of values. I want to label members who have these values as 1 (must have a value beginning with 99, must have a value beginning with 77[1-9], and have either 77014 or G6 or a value ending with T)

I created a vector of all the values I'm interested in based on the original data:

```
vec <- rad %>% select(proc1) %>% filter(str_detect(proc1, '^77[1-9]|^77014|^G6|^99|T$'))
vec1 <- vec %>% distinct(proc1)
```

and then did this:

```
rad[, new := +(proc1 %in% vec1$proc1), by = enrolid]
```

but is there a way where instead of it being optional to have any of those values and label as 1, it only assigns a 1 IF the member has all of the required values?

example data:

```
structure(list(enrolid = c("1005501701", "1005501701", "1005569804", 
"1005578501", "1005613901", "1005613901", "1005613901", "1005618402", 
"1005618402", "1005623302", "1005623302", "1005623302", "1005623302", 
"1005623302", "1005623302", "1005623302", "1005623302", "1005623302", 
"1005623302", "1005623302", "1005623302"), proc1 = c("99211", 
"99213", "99213", "99214", "99213", "99214", "99214", "99214", 
"99214", "99213", "99213", "99214", "99214", "77263", "77280", 
"77412", "77427", "77412", "99214", "99204", "99214")), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000260f6181ef0>)
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to run the code for your example data.

Comment: @rjen it works, if you remove the part from the `.internal` ...pointer` while copy/pasting

Comment: @akrun: Indeed.

Comment: @akrun: I didn't post the question. But maybe there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think before I commented

Comment: @vizidea: Are you looking for an approach that identifies entries that contain a selection of substrings? If yes, are these substrings allowed to overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use another condition with `all`

```
rad[,  new := all(vec1$proc1 %in% proc1) & proc1 %in% vec1$proc1, by = enrolid]
```